# Exceptions when using a name of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm reading a C++ 11 book and the author says

> As with any array, when we use the name of a multidimensional array, it is
>   automatically converted to a pointer to the first element in the array.

Then the author mentions, when we are passing a name of an array to `decltype` it is not converted to a pointer to the first element in the array.

If we have an array like this: `int arr[5][3]`, and then type this: `decltype(arr) test`. Type of `test` will be deduced correctly and `test` will be an array of 5 arrays of 3 ints.

My question is, are there any more exceptions (besides the `decltype` one) of the rule mentioned earlier?

Thanks.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same....choose one

Comment: @SouravGhosh fixed.

Comment: `decltype` is not an exception to the rule, since it isn't a function call.

Comment: @Michael Naifield  For example when an array is used in the sizeof operator.

Comment: As a sidenote, C and C++ are closer than almost any two other languages out there. The K&R book for 'the original' C standard, ANSI C89, all code examples compile with a C++ compiler as well.

Comment: @ErikAlapää That may be true for C89 but both C and C++ have newer standards and a valid C11 program may not be a valid C++14 program.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, but my point is that a lot of valid C is also valid, or trivially changed to valid, C++, that is why some people tend to ask questions about the common subset of C and C++ and mark question with both C and C++ tags.

Answer (score 1):

For example when an array is used by reference or when an array is used in some operators like `sizeof` operator or `&` operator the array is not converted to pointer to its first element.

Consider for example this program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };
    decltype( auto ) b = ( a );
}
```

This program will compile successfully and the array a will not be converted to a pointer.

However if to remove the parentheses around a then this program will not compile because the array a will be converted a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };
    decltype( auto ) b = a;
}
```

Comment: I understood what happens.  Could you please also explain why this happens?

Comment: @BatCoder When an expression is used in parentheses in such a declaration then the deduced type is a referenced type. For example for the shown first program the deduced type will be int ( & )[2].

Comment: What about using the name of an array in a range-based for loop? Is it being converted to a pointer to its first element there?

Comment: @MichaelNaifield An array used in the range-base for statement is not converted to a pointer. But the range-based for statement uses expressions a and a + dimension( a 0 where a is an array name.